# Simple PHP Character Escaping Issue

Tags: php, html, variables, escaping, quotes

I am trying to use a php variable for an image...should be easy, right?

But have spent some time looking over the bellow code and cannot see the error. I suspect there is an issue with escaped characters, although cannot put my finger on it.

```
<?php 
$image=http://www.infiniteplastic.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/Hat_Poker.jpg;
echo '<img src="$image" class="bg">' ;
?>
```

Appears as...

```
' ; ?>
```

It looks like the php stops after "bg"> and reads the following four characters as html, but am not sure why it would do that. Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Didn't you notice how everything after the `//` becomes a comment?

Answer (score 2):

First, wrap the string in quotes

```
$image='http://www.infiniteplastic.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/Hat_Poker.jpg';
```

and...

You're wrapping a variable in single quotes. Cannot do it.

wrong

```
echo '<img src="$image" class="bg">' ;
```

right

```
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" class="bg">' ;
```

Comment: fixing both does not change the output

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with this solution, probably you fix and created another problem. Good if you can show us what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Missing quotes around the string:

```
$image='http://www.infiniteplastic.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/Hat_Poker.jpg';
       ^                                                                       ^
```

Comment: That fixes one problem, what about the `$variable` inside 'single quotes'?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the quotes!

```
$image='http://www.infiniteplastic.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/Hat_Poker.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $image='your image link here. sorry i cant post image link just because im new here'; 
echo "<img src='$image' class='bg'>" ; 
?>
```

this solves your problem.
ive tried that in my localhost.

your problem is because of the ' and the " 
you must learn how to use that properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things wrong here. I'm going to try and make it clearer for you:

```
<?php 
$image = "http://www.infiniteplastic.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/Hat_Poker.jpg";
echo "<img src='".$image."' class='bg' alt='dont forget alt tag' />" ;
?>
```

- Missing quotes around variable
- img tag needs to be self-closing
- src still needs quotes around it's link

Tried this on my server and it works.